# Desplegar aplicacion web de Java en un vps con ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, vps, war

Muy buenas,

tengo contratado un vps, para alojar un aplicacion con dominio publico. Y estoy configurando tomcat, lo tengo ya instalado y cuando quiero desplegar el .war, se me abre el en el explorador de archivos, el explorador de mi portatil. Claro aunque pueda cargar desde mi equipo local en el servidor el archivo, dspues da error al desplegarlo. Por lo visto hay que configurar el archivo context.xml. Las dudas que tengo es, donde esta ubicado el archivo context.xml en ubuntu?. Lo he buscado en /opt/tomcat y en ese arbol de directorios lo tengo vacio, en /tomcat no aparece ninguna carpeta, no se si eso es normal? (en /etc si que estan todos los archivos de tomcat que deberian). Y despues la otra duda en el archivo context.xml como indico que se pueda desplegar .war desde otro equipo diferente al del servidor?

Si sabeis otra forma de desplegar el .war aunque sea por linea de comandos os lo agradeceria. Llevaba en mente pasar por ftp el .war al servidor y luego desplegarlo por comandos, pero no he encontrado por foros como hacerlo.

Adjunto captura de lo que indica tomcat al tratar de subir el archivo por otro equipo que no es el servidor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda,

saludos

Comment: Revisa desde `/usr/share/tomcat#`. El war lo podrías copiar a `/usr/share/tomcat#-root/` y el context que buscas podría estar en `/usr/share/tomcat#-root/manager/META-INF/`.

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].